# Is Windows really running in a virtual machine?

Tags: windows, operating-system, virtual-machine, virtualization, hypervisor

I've found [this blog post from from Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=99265) claiming that:

> Strictly speaking, what it actually represents is the resources of the other virtual machines, **since Windows itself is running in a virtual machine under the hypervisor**. You may not be explicitly using the hypervisor, but some other features are built on top of the hypervisor.

I couldn't find any source supporting this claim.

Is a host Windows operating system really running inside a virtual machine under the hypervisor?

Comment: Raymond *is* a source. He's a developer at MS, has been for more than a decade, and has worked on various parts of the OS including the kernel and shell. He is a definitive source.

Answer (score 0):

`VBS` [Virtualization-based Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-vbs)

> Virtualization-based security, or VBS, uses hardware virtualization
> features to create and isolate a secure region of memory from the
> normal operating system. Windows can use this "virtual secure mode" to
> host a number of security solutions, providing them with greatly
> increased protection from vulnerabilities in the operating system, and
> preventing the use of malicious exploits which attempt to defeat
> protections.
>
> One such example security solution is Hypervisor-Enforced Code
> Integrity (HVCI), commonly referred to as Memory integrity, which uses
> VBS to significantly strengthen code integrity policy enforcement.
> Kernel mode code integrity checks all kernel mode drivers and binaries
> before they're started, and prevents unsigned drivers or system files
> from being loaded into system memory.
>
> VBS uses the Windows hypervisor to create this virtual secure mode,
> and to enforce restrictions which protect vital system and operating
> system resources, or to protect security assets such as authenticated
> user credentials. With the increased protections offered by VBS, even
> if malware gains access to the OS kernel the possible exploits can be
> greatly limited and contained, because the hypervisor can prevent the
> malware from executing code or accessing platform secrets.
>
> Similarly, user mode configurable code integrity policy checks
> applications before they're loaded, and will only start executables
> that are signed by known, approved signers. HVCI leverages VBS to run
> the code integrity service inside a secure environment, providing
> stronger protections against kernel viruses and malware. The
> hypervisor, the most privileged level of system software, sets and
> enforces page permissions across all system memory. Pages are only
> made executable after code integrity checks inside the secure region
> have passed, and executable pages are not writable. That way, even if
> there are vulnerabilities like a buffer overflow that allow malware to
> attempt to modify memory, code pages cannot be modified, and modified
> memory cannot be made executable.

`VSM`  [Virtual Secure Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/tlfs/vsm)

> Virtual Secure Mode (VSM) is a set of hypervisor capabilities and
> enlightenments offered to host and guest partitions which enables the
> creation and management of new security boundaries within operating
> system software. VSM is the hypervisor facility on which Windows
> security features including Device Guard, Credential Guard, virtual
> TPMs and shielded VMs are based. These security features were
> introduced in Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016.
>
> VSM enables operating system software in the root and guest partitions
> to create isolated regions of memory for storage and processing of
> system security assets. Access to these isolated regions is controlled
> and granted solely through the hypervisor, which is a highly
> privileged, highly trusted part of the system’s Trusted Compute Base
> (TCB). Because the hypervisor runs at a higher privilege level than
> operating system software and has exclusive control of key system
> hardware resources such as memory access permission controls in the
> CPU MMU and IOMMU early in system initialization, the hypervisor can
> protect these isolated regions from unauthorized access, even from
> operating system software (e.g., OS kernel and device drivers) with
> supervisor mode access (i.e. CPL0, or “Ring 0”).
>
> With this architecture, even if normal system level software running
> in supervisor mode (e.g. kernel, drivers, etc.) is compromised by
> malicious software, the assets in isolated regions protected by the
> hypervisor can remain secured.